# yii - create nested cgridview

Tags: yii

Is it possible to create nested table using cgridview?

I'd like to have the final output as follows

```
| Transaction     | Total |
| T-001           |  $100 | 
      | Item | Price |      // here is the nested table
      | I-1  |  $50  |
      | I-2  |  $50  |
| T-002           |  $90  |
      | Item | Price |      // here is the nested table
      | I-3  |  $90  |
```

I know you can do this using a custom template, but i'd like a neater solution using a widget like CGRidView.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If nested table is inside cell then you can, just create function in your model that will render table and return content. You can set third parameter of widget function to true to return content. If you want to enable pagination for nested table then be sure to manually set  widget id and allow ajax update.

In model:

```
function getNestedTable() {

  return Yii::app()->controller->widget(..., ..., true);

}
```

In columns definition use:

```
'columns' => array(
  array(
  'name' => 'nestedTable',
  'type' => 'raw'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to use custom functions in your CActiveRecord model (if you've a CActiveDataprovider for the grid), and put that 'nested table' as normal column:

```
| Transaction  | Item | Price |    Total |
------------------------------------------
| T-001        | I-1  |  $50  |     $100 | 
               | I-2  |  $50  | 
------------------------------------------
| T-002        | I-3  |  $90  |     $90  |
------------------------------------------
```

In your model you've to define get functions that return data in HTML with line breaks (for  example with a br:

```
class Item extends CActiveRecord {
...
public function getIdItems()
{
    $string = '';
    foreach($this->items as $item) {
        if ($string != '') $string .= '<br/>';
        $string .= ' '.$item->textId; // 'I-3', 'I-2'...
    }
    return $string;
}
public function getPriceItems()
{
    $string = '';
    foreach($this->items as $item) {
        if ($string != '') $string .= '<br/>';
        $string .= ' '.$item->price; // $50, $90...
    }
    return $string;
}
...
}
```

And to show the new columns in your grid:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'anotacionesGrid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'transaction',
        'idItems:html:Item',
        'priceItems:html:Price',
        'total'
    )
);
```